# MongoDB & Spring Boot: How to get only specific sub document from an array based on filter values?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am kind of new to MongoDB and trying to write a query using Spring Boot and Java to fetch only the matching subdocument from an Array, but however I try, I keep getting the entire document in the response.

My sample dataset looks like this:

```
{
"storeId": "xxxxx",
"bu": "xxxxx",
"items": [
  {
    "itemId": "1234",
    "itemName": "x",
    "price": "10.0",
  },
  {
    "itemId": "43556",
    "itemName": "y",
    "price": "1.0"
  }]
}

{
"storeId": "yyyyyy",
"bu": "xxxxx",
"items": [
  {
    "itemId": "1234",
    "itemName": "x",
    "price": "0.0",
  },
  {
    "itemId": "67654",
    "itemName": "y",
    "price": "10.0"
  }]
}
```

I want to filter on items.itemId = 1234 and items.price =10.0, for which I am expecting the following output:

```
{
"storeId": "xxxxx",
"bu": "xxxxx",
"items": [
  {
    "itemId": "1234",
    "itemName": "x",
    "price": "10.0",
  }]
}
```

However I am getting

```
{
"storeId": "xxxxx",
"bu": "xxxxx",
"items": [
  {
    "itemId": "1234",
    "itemName": "x",
    "price": "10.0",
  }]
}

{
"storeId": "yyyyyy",
"bu": "xxxxx",
"items": [
  {
    "itemId": "1234",
    "itemName": "x",
    "price": "0.0",
  }]
}
```

Can someone please help me in writing this query with Spring boot and mongotempalte framework?

Comment: Have you tried projection with elemMatch?